# Error on using Category in Obj-C library, which was used in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift2

I have an library written in Obj-c. And I wrote an additional method to NSMutableArray by follow this [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html).

`.h file` look like this

```
@interface NSMutableArray (Queue)
-(id) dequeue;
-(void) enqueue:(id)obj;  
@end
```

And it run fine in Obj-C project but when I import this library into swift project, the part that using above method got `NSInvalidArgumentException unrecognized selector sent to instance`.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '-[__NSCFString objectFromJSONString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9e69fb6650'
```

Comment: In what way is that error related to your category?

Comment: Please show "the part that using above method".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add -ObjC to your Other Linker Flags(found under Build Settings in your target).

Comment: That only applies if the object files are within a static library.  I didn't see anything about libraries in the question.